# Computer stuck after quitting installation

Tags: system-installation

I was installing ubuntu 15.04 when I realized I needed to partition disks first. So I quit the installer, and my screen turns off. My computer will not turn off though, even if I hit the power button or hold it down. I don't want to break it by unplugging it. What should I do? My normal OS is Windows 10 64bit.

Comment: Don't forget to go to your windows settings and disable fastboot and then fully shut windows down properly or it will technically be in a hibernated state and ubuntu will not see your windows partition during installation!!!

Answer (score 1):

You could try to hold the button longer, it sounds weird to me that it won't turn of using the power button. If it still does not want to turn off, the best thing you can is unplug the computer, as one time doing that won't mess up the system. (Or you have bad luck.) And why did you stopped the installation in the first place? Ubuntu can do the partitioning for you!

Comment: Did that right before you replied, thanks though! I'm going to install it from a USB onto a drive that has a couple other files on it, and I'm having trouble telling which drive is which and how to partition it exactly. I have two of the exact same drives so according to Ubuntu there's no difference that I can tell.

Comment: That sounds to me like you have two same drive models from the sam manufacturer, what you can do for the files if you want to backup those is mounting the drive with the files, in the Live System, which you can run of the USB directly, by clicking "Try Ubuntu". As for partitioning, I would recommend to also use the Live System, and searching for GParted. When you have started the program you can find all your drives in the right upper corner of the GParted window. Select the correct drive, go to Device, and select "Erase MBR". This should erase all partitions. Run setup, install to drive!

Comment: @Daxxa use gparted to label the target drive so you can tell the difference or disconnect the other drive during installation. Drives are listed as /dev/sda, /dev/sdb, . . .  etc. Partitions are listed as /dev/sda1, /dev/sda2, . . . or /dev/sdb1, /dev/sdb2 . . . etc.